# How can I permanently save AVAudioRecorder files for later access?

Tags: avaudiorecorder

I have my code all set up to actually record the files. What I need, though, is a way to see where they are all saved and list them in a `UITableView`. I'm not asking the the implementation for the table; I only need a way to see where they are all saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your data is saved into your application's document folder. You can access it with:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0)  {
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Assign an array to get a list of all your recorded files.

Answer (score 0):

Your url where you are going to save the recorded file:

```
NSURL *urlOfRecordedFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"5@/recordFile.caf",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePaht]]];
```

And here is the actual path of you file

```
NSLog(@"%@",url);
```